# $ undefined error

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm developing a Chrome extension and I've got the following...

```
 $(document).keypress(function(event){ resizeDialogIFrame(overlaydiv, iFrame.contentWindow); });
```

But when executed I'm getting the following error...

`Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined`

However, `$('form[name="gs"]').attr('action');` is working fine elsewhere in the page.. What's going wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If jQuery was loaded correctly (?) try this pattern to make sure `$` references the `jQuery` object.

```
(function($) {
     $(function() {
         $(document).keypress(function(event){ resizeDialogIFrame(overlaydiv, iFrame.contentWindow); });
     });
}(jQuery));
```

If that doesn't help, check if jQuery was loaded correctly. Thatfore, call

```
alert('jQuery' in window);
```

if that alerts `false`, something is wrong.

Comment: The alert returns true, however the proposed solution doesn't seem to of worked. Would the fact I'm doing this code in an iframe be effecting it?

Comment: @Skizit: not at all. But be aware of that an `<iframe>` has its **own** DOM, so you would need to include jQuery within the iframe aswell.